# Christmas word: Anti-me would get your attention with no exceptions

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> I am a snowing Christmas word.
>
> Anti-me would would get your attention with no exceptions!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there aren't all that many snowing things, so you might be

> **Ice**

*Anti-me would would get your attention with no exceptions!*

That would then be your polar opposite,

> **not**ice

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative answer

> Cover

I am a snowing Christmas word.

> *Snow cover* means a layer of snow on the ground

Anti-me would would get your attention with no exceptions!

> **Dis**cover means to find unexpectedly or during a search, something which would certainly get your attention